# Magento (SOAP) API catalog_product_attribute_media.list return storeView

Tags: php, api, magento, soap

I'm using Magento 1.9 SOAP API to manage products with our [PIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_information_management). We're using Magento's multi-store feature and some products are available on multiple stores but with different images.

Is there a way to populate the store views, which are assigned to the images inside the API response?

The default response from `catalog_product_attribute_media.list` according to [the Magento 1.x SOAP API documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttributeMedia/catalog_product_attribute_media.list.html) is:

- file
- label
- position
- exclude
- url
- types

Maybe I'm going to hack `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Media_Api`... but I hope there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If store code is not specified explicitly during `catalog_product_attribute_media.list` call, the result will contain only images assigned to the default store view (those images which are set in the admin panel, when no custom store view is selected in "Choose Store View" dropdown).

To get images assigned in specific store view, please use optional `storeView` parameter of `catalog_product_attribute_media.list`. Thus store view will be known for all retrieved images. No need to hack `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Media_Api`.